# Kotlin add custom method to stream chaining

Tags: kotlin, java-stream

I need to add a custom method (which is a Consumer) to the dot chaining in stream api, i not sure how to do it, following is my code.

If that is not possible, is there anyway to do it with other operation? Maybe like with `.map` or something else?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var countries: List<String> = listOf("India", "Germany", "Japan")

    var firstCountry = countries.stream()
                                .filter{it == "Germany"}
                                .performOperation{}    //not sure what to do here
                                .findFirst()

    println(firstCountry)

}


fun performOperation(country: String) {
    if(country.length > 3) {
        throw InvalidLengthException("Error")
    }
    
   //do some operation, won't return any value
   doCustomOperation(country)
}
```

Comment: looking for `forEach`? what is the findFirst for?

Answer (score 1):

You may already be aware that when it comes to steams there are two types of operations, one is your `map`, `filter` etc. known as intermediate opeartion and others are terminal operations such as `forEach`. You said your custom operation wont return any value, hence making it a terminal operation. moreover it seems to me that you want to perform same operation for all the elements, basically a forEach. for this you can define an extension function on Stream as

```
fun <T> Stream<T>.someOperation(operation: (T) -> Unit){
    this.forEach { operation(it) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways to do what you want.

```
    var firstCountry = countries.stream()
                                .filter{it == "Germany"}
                                .also(::performOperation)
                                .findFirst()
```

The :: is a function reference and is basically the same as `.also { performOperation(it)}`

The second one would be to make your own extension method on list. I wouldn't recommend it until you understand kotlin lambdas and extension methods

```
fun Stream<String>.performOperation(): Stream<String> {
  for(country in this) {
    if(country.length > 3) {
        throw InvalidLengthException("Error")
      }
    
   doCustomOperation(country)
   } 
  return this
}
```

You would just call that one like `.performOperation()` where you have the `.performOperation{}`

Comment: the `return this` gives me error: `Type mismatch. Required: Unit, Found: Stream<String>`

Comment: Oh yeah I missed that, fixed hopefully

Comment: Alltough I think you should use the also instead, as it more clearly communicates intent